# Reloading a Powershell Class Module Without Restarting the Shell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm currently importing my custom Powershell datatypes using the "Using Module" keyword and instantiating using the "New-Object" cmdlet.

Example:

```
Using Module .\MyClass.psm1
$a = New-Object -TypeName MyClass -ArgumentList ($param1, $param2)
```

My issue is that I would like to modify the module and reload the datatype without having to restart the shell, but I can't seem to find a way to do this with the "Using" keyword. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799697/make-powershell-script-run-cmdlets-in-global-scope

Comment: The "Import-Module" command doesn't import classes only functions and variables. The best way I've found to do this is with the "Using Module" keyword. The "Remove-Module" command similarly does not remove classes.